# The probability of drawing a type of card from a deck with 2 draws.

Tags: probability

Let's propose that I have a deck with 16 cards, with the following cards: `4 A cards, 4 B cards, 4 C cards and 4 D cards`.

I know how to calculate the chance of drawing an `A card` from this deck with a single draw: `good draws / number of cards` which cames up to **25%**.

How could I calculate the same chance percentage, if I am able to draw two cards from this deck? Could you give me a formula to use, for these kind of calculations, in which I can change the deck size, the deck composition or even the number of possible draws also?

Comment: Are you familiar with permutations/combinatorics?

Comment: Yes, but this problem still eludes me. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The probability for obtaining 2 from the 4 A-cards, when drawing 2 from all 16 cards, is $$\left.{\dbinom 42}\middle/{\dbinom {16}2}\right.$$The probability for obtaining exactly 1 from the 4 A-cards, when drawing 2 from all 16 cards, is $$\left.{\dbinom 41}\middle/{\dbinom {16}2}\right.$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Your second probability should be ${4\choose 1}{12\choose 1}/{16\choose 2}$

Comment: Yes. Indeed.  Opps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways.

**(1)** You could create the sample space of all two-drawings. Numbering the cards $A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, ...$ etc.  You'll have $(A1,A2), (A1,A3),$ $..., (B1, A1)$, etc. A total of $16\cdot 15$ possibilities (without replacement), of which you can form the ratio the same way as you did for the simpler problem.

**(2)** You do not need to write out the sample space, however. You could simply count. Consider the mutually exclusive events:

$(E) \,\, \text{Exactly one A is drawn, and it is drawn 1st... (} \, 4\cdot 12 \text { ways.)}$
$(F) \,\, \text{Exactly one A is drawn, and it is drawn 2nd.. (} \,12\cdot 4 \text { ways.)}$
$(G) \,\, \text{Exactly two A's are drawn... (} \, 4\cdot 3 \text { ways.)}$

The event *At least one $A$* then is given by the union of these events, and so:

$$P(\text{At least one A}) = P(E\cup F \cup G) = \dfrac{4\cdot 12}{16\cdot 15}+\dfrac{12\cdot 4}{16\cdot 15}+\dfrac{4\cdot 3}{16\cdot 15}$$

**(3)** A (perhaps) quicker approach would be to use a formula:

$$P(\text{At least one A}) = 1- P(\text{no A is Drawn})$$

The second term above, the probability no A is drawn, can be calculated as

$$P(1^{st} \text{ not an A})\cdot P(2^{nd} \text{ not an A, assuming the first is not an A})$$

$$ = \dfrac{12}{16}\cdot \dfrac{11}{15}$$

Answer (score 1):

If, like in your case, you have $16$ cards, four of each color, red, green, blue and black, then you're right that the first card being black has a probability of $.25$.

In order to find out the probability of *at least* one black card, for example, it's easier to find out the probably of *no* black cards, and then subtract that from $1$, the total probability space. This is somewhat useful in this case, but much more applicable in larger spaces.

In order to find the probability of missing a black card both times, you just figure out the probability of drawing any other type of card, which is just $\frac{12}{16}$. If we then draw another card, we know that we've lost one non-black card from our total, which is now $15$, so the probability that we draw a second non-black card is $\frac{11}{15}$. This continues on for each non-black card you don't draw. Once you pick as many non-black cards as you want ($n$ of them to be general), you end up with:

$$\frac{12}{16}\times\frac{11}{15}\times...\times\frac{12-n+1}{16-n+1}$$

Once you get this number, which is the probability of missing a black card $n$ times, you can subtract it from $1$, the total probability space, to get you the probability of at least one black card.

Comment: This gives me the probability, that BOTH cards will be `A cards`, and not the probability that at least 1 card will be an `A card` from the 2 drawn.

Comment: My apologies, that's how your question read. I'll edit it.

Comment: Hopefully the edits help.